# Gradle issues in Android studio 2.1.1

Tags: android-studio

I am new to android studio. I am using android studio version 2.1.1. I have to run an application from Github. The problem I am facing is that whenever I run the application , I get this error,

Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.

I have even installed android support repository after following some tutorial. This did not help. I have also tried to find the versions of gradle that are compatible with Android studio 2.1.1. I dont know how to solve this issue

Comment: Is the gradle version of your github project is compatible with the one install in your android studio? check it once.

Comment: The information about imported project is:  Gradle Version=2.2, Android Plugin Version=1.0.0 and Android Plugin repository=maven Central. Whereas The Gradle version of the android studio is 2.10, Android Plugin Version=2.1.2 and Android Plugin repository=jcentre

Comment: Furthormore, I am also getting this error, "The system cannot find the file specified".  and Error running build: Module "Module name" is not backed by gradle